# Why I'm not getting any kind of output in SDL?

Tags: sdl

Here's the code that supposed to display the texture:

```
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, mainRaster.getOutput,null,null);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

The code that runs the update process:

```
if(doubleBufferRegisters[0] == 0){
                doubleBufferRegisters[0] = 1;
                doubleBufferRegisters[1] = 0;
            }else{
                doubleBufferRegisters[0] = 0;
                doubleBufferRegisters[1] = 1;
            }
    SDL_LockTexture(frameBuffer[doubleBufferRegisters[0]], null, &fbData[doubleBufferRegisters[0]], &fbPitch[doubleBufferRegisters[0]]);
             1);

            for(int i ; i < layerList.length ; i++){
                layerList[i].updateRaster(fbData[doubleBufferRegisters[0]], fbPitch[doubleBufferRegisters[0]], palette);
            }
            SDL_UnlockTexture(frameBuffer[doubleBufferRegisters[0]]);
            r = false;
```

My engine uses CPU based rendering for the most part. I had to remove some of the overhead, as the engine first had to create an SDL_Surface from the proprietary bitmap format, then an SDL_Texture, now the palette conversion is done on the fly, enabling the use of transparencies and non-paletted graphics. However, an old problem came back after this, namely I'm getting a black screen. Even back then it was almost impossible to fix and still don't know what I did to make it work (other that trial and error with small modifications). Bypassing the "double buffering" doesn't change anything.

I'm writing my engine in D, however any help for C++ also would be helpful.

Comment: Is there a member variable called `getOutput`, or are you actually missing parenthesis there? (Or is that some D stuff?)

Comment: Yes, there is, however I obscured it. That function returns the unlocked texture now, as it gives a bit of boost on the framerate. Changing to return the same exact texture only results in lower update rate, still no output.

Comment: I think you would have to provide more code. As a side note, you should try coloring your buffers with a static red or something to see if the problem is the SDL rendering, your CPU rendering or potentially something else.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems I had some problem with the alpha-blending algorithm I wrote in the in-line assembler, that uses MMX. While I could test that the code actually works and wrote actual data to the framebuffer, the image didn't show on the window.

Here's the assembly part to the alpha-blending:

```
asm{
            //mov       edi,dest;                         
            //mov       ebx,src;                          
            //mov       ecx,len;
            mov     EDX, alpha;

            //movzx   EAX,DL;
            movq    MM7,alphaMMXmul_const1;

            shl     EAX,16;
            add     EAX,EDX;
            mov     [alphaMMXmul_0],EAX;
            mov     [alphaMMXmul_0 + 4],EAX ;                     
            movq    MM6,alphaMMXmul_0; //mm6(X) = alpha (4 words)        
            pxor    MM5,MM5;
            psubusw MM7,MM6; //mm7(Y) = 256 – alpha (4 words)      

            //ALIGN 16                                    
            //  MixAlphaMMX32_MainLoop:                               

            //movd      MM0,[EDI]; //mm0(A) = 0 0 0 0 | 0 Ra Ga Ba            
            movd        MM0,dest;                     
            //movd      mm1,[ebx]; //mm1(B) = 0 0 0 0 | 0 Rb Gb Bb            
            movd        MM1,src;

            punpcklbw   MM0,MM5; //mm0 = 0 0 0 Ra | 0 Ga 0 Ba             
            punpcklbw   MM1,MM5; //mm1 = 0 0 0 Rb | 0 Gb 0 Bb             
            pmullw      MM0,MM6; //mm0 = 0 Ra*X | Ga*X Ba*X           
            pmullw      MM1,MM7; //mm1 = 0 Rb*Y | Gb*Y Bb*Y               
            paddusw     MM0,MM1; //mm0 = 0 Ra*X+Rb*y | Ga*X+Gb*y Ba*X+Bb*Y     
            psrlw       MM0,8; //mm0 = 0 0 0 Rc | 0 Gc 0 Bc           
            packuswb    MM0,MM0; //mm0 = 0 0 0 0 | 0 Rc Gc Bc             
            //movd      [edi],mm0;
            movd        dest,MM0;

            //dec       ecx ;             

            emms        ;
        }
```

Going to use some non-scalar method until I come up with something better. The assembly code had built-in type conversion, most samples I could find on the internet even used floating point operations. Then I can focus on fixing the framerate issues either by reducing the redraw calls (by using a different framebuffer for all layers), or finding a faster way to update the framebuffer.